# Enabling content delivery in old sandbox org

Tags: sandbox, setup

Current issue I have is installing a new version of a package on an old sandbox org but it gives me the error

"Class MY_CLASS: Invalid type: Schema.ContentDistribution".

I am trying to enable content delivery on an old sandbox org so I can resolve the error and install the package. However, I can't seem to find the content deliveries and public link section in set up. I double checked on a scratch org and the setting definitely exists. Am I missing another setting I need to enable or do I need to file a case with Salesforce directly? Is the error maybe related another setting I need to enable or maybe the sandbox version?

Guide I'm following: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_delivery_about.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Please [Log a case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5) with Salesforce Support and provide the org Id where you want Content Delivery to be enabled

In general, content delivery can enabled by following below steps

> Click Setup | Customize | Content Deliveries | Settings and select the
> Enable content deliveries checkbox.

Setting up Content Deliveries
Available in: All Editions

User Permissions Needed
To enable content deliveries: "Customize Application"

If this permission is missing from setup, Feature Activation team will enable required permissions from the backend to make it available in setup